# Please expain the syntax of the gradle task definition "<<"

Tags: gradle

The Gradle User Guide [shows](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N101BE) a syntax for creating a task that I don't understand:

```
task hello << {
    println 'Hello world!'
}
```

What is the `<<` doing there?
The [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767888/what-is-the-difference-between-these-task-definition-syntaxes-in-gradle) was a little enlightening but I still don't know exactly what `<<` is. Is `<<` a groovy thing or a gradle thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a groovy thing. Operators can be overloaded in Groovy by declaring a method on the object the operator is applied on. In this case, the method is [leftShift()](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task%3aleftShift%28groovy.lang.Closure%29).

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading for more information.

Comment: Operator overloading...yuk.  Quality of this answer...GREAT!  Thanks.

Comment: And what is `hello` from the Groovy perspective? It's kind of a string? Here is the [`task()` Groovydoc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#task(java.lang.String))

Comment: Quite frankly, I don't know.

Answer (score 12):

Bob's answer covers the Groovy side.  For the Gradle portion, << corresponds to doLast on task, adding another action to the end of the task's list of actions.