# Custom Gradle Plugin Exec task with extension does not use input properly

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am following the [Writing Custom Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) section of the Gradle documentation, specifically the part about [Getting input from the build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#N147BD). The following example provided by the documentation works exactly as expected:

```
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

greeting.message = 'Hi from Gradle'

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Add the 'greeting' extension object
        project.extensions.create("greeting", GreetingPluginExtension)
        // Add a task that uses the configuration
        project.task('hello') << {
            println project.greeting.message
        }
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    def String message = 'Hello from GreetingPlugin'
}
```

Output:

```
> gradle -q hello
Hi from Gradle
```

I'd like to have the custom plugin execute an external command (using the [Exec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)), but when changing the task to a type (including types other than Exec such as [Copy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html)), the input to the build stops working properly:

```
// previous and following sections omitted for brevity
project.task('hello', type: Exec) {
    println project.greeting.message
}
```

Output:

```
> gradle -q hello
Hello from GreetingPlugin
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not related to the type of the task, it's a typical `<<` misunderstanding.

**When you write**

```
project.task('hello') << {
    println project.greeting.message
}
```

and execute `gradle hello`, the following happens:

*configuration phase*

1. apply custom plugin
2. create task hello
3. set greeting.message = 'Hi from Gradle'

*executon phase*

1. run task with empty body
2. execute << closure { `println project.greeting.message` }

in this scenario output is Hi from Gradle

**When you write**

```
project.task('hello', type: Exec) {
    println project.greeting.message
}
```

and execute `gradle hello`, the following happens

*configuration phase*

1. apply custom plugin
2. create exec task hello
3. execute task init closure `println project.greeting.message`
4. set greeting.message = 'Hi from Gradle' **(too late, it was printed in step 3)**

the rest of workflow does not matter.

---

So, small details matter. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767888/what-is-the-difference-between-these-task-definition-syntaxes-in-gradle) the explanation of the same topic.

---

**Solution:**

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.afterEvaluate {
        project.task('hello', type: Exec) {
            println project.greeting.message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This only explains _why_ the issue is occurring though. Do you know of a solution or an alternative to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Well, I did actually want to solve the problem... Like most people asking questions on this site. :) Thanks for the solution.